# TPT Delimited Data Parsing error: Too many columns in row 1

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm trying to load data througt TPT. While execution i have this kind or error :

> W_0_o_CSV_job[1]: TPT19134 !ERROR! Fatal data error processing file
>   'C:\Users\291506\Desktop\testdico.csv'. Delimited Data Parsing error:
>   Too many columns in row 1.

I tried to change the format of import file but nothing change...

Here is my script :

```
/* 1 */  
/* 2 */  
/* 3 */  DEFINE JOB CSV_job
/* 4 */  (
/* 5 */     DEFINE OPERATOR W_1_o_CSV_job
/* 6 */     TYPE LOAD
/* 7 */     SCHEMA *
/* 8 */     ATTRIBUTES
/* 9 */     (
/* 10 */        VARCHAR UserName, 
/* 11 */        VARCHAR UserPassword, 
/* 12 */        VARCHAR LogTable, 
/* 13 */        VARCHAR TargetTable, 
/* 14 */        INTEGER BufferSize, 
/* 15 */        INTEGER ErrorLimit, 
/* 16 */        INTEGER MaxSessions, 
/* 17 */        INTEGER MinSessions, 
/* 18 */        INTEGER TenacityHours, 
/* 19 */        INTEGER TenacitySleep, 
/* 20 */        VARCHAR AccountID, 
/* 21 */        VARCHAR DateForm, 
/* 22 */        VARCHAR ErrorTable1, 
/* 23 */        VARCHAR ErrorTable2, 
/* 24 */        VARCHAR NotifyExit, 
/* 25 */        VARCHAR NotifyExitIsDLL, 
/* 26 */        VARCHAR NotifyLevel, 
/* 27 */        VARCHAR NotifyMethod, 
/* 28 */        VARCHAR NotifyString, 
/* 29 */        VARCHAR PauseAcq, 
/* 30 */        VARCHAR PrivateLogName, 
/* 31 */        VARCHAR TdpId, 
/* 32 */        VARCHAR TraceLevel, 
/* 33 */        VARCHAR WorkingDatabase
/* 34 */    );
/* 35 */  
/* 36 */    DEFINE SCHEMA W_0_s_CSV_job
/* 37 */    (
/* 38 */        REGLE_OFS VARCHAR(50),
/* 39 */        OFS_FIELD_BC801 VARCHAR(50),
/* 40 */        ME131 VARCHAR(50),
/* 41 */        DATA_TYPE VARCHAR(50),
/* 42 */        DATA_TYPOLOGY VARCHAR(50),
/* 43 */        FU_REF VARCHAR(50),
/* 44 */        FU_FIELD VARCHAR(250),
/* 45 */        FU_FIELD_EN VARCHAR(250),
/* 46 */        CODE_RADAR VARCHAR(50),
/* 47 */        REGLE_RADAR VARCHAR(50),
/* 48 */        DEFINITION_RADAR VARCHAR(5000),
/* 49 */        MODIFICATION_REGLE_RADAR VARCHAR(50),
/* 50 */        ANACREDIT VARCHAR(50),
/* 51 */        ANACREDIT_CRITICAL_FLAG VARCHAR(50),
/* 52 */        NPE_FBE VARCHAR(50),
/* 53 */        CRE VARCHAR(50),
/* 54 */        IFRS9 VARCHAR(50),
/* 55 */        IFRS9_CRITICAL_FLAG VARCHAR(50),
/* 56 */        SHS_2018 VARCHAR(50),
/* 57 */        SHS_CRITICAL_FLAG VARCHAR(50),
/* 58 */        STRESS_TEST VARCHAR(50),
/* 59 */        STOP_1_BMRC VARCHAR(50),
/* 60 */        MANDATORY_OPTIMA VARCHAR(50),
/* 61 */        FRANCE_REPORTING_Data VARCHAR(50),
/* 62 */        DEFAULTING_RDI VARCHAR(50)
/* 63 */    );
/* 64 */  
/* 65 */    DEFINE OPERATOR W_0_o_CSV_job
/* 66 */    TYPE DATACONNECTOR PRODUCER
/* 67 */    SCHEMA W_0_s_CSV_job
/* 68 */    ATTRIBUTES
/* 69 */    (
/* 70 */        VARCHAR FileName, 
/* 71 */        VARCHAR Format, 
/* 72 */        VARCHAR OpenMode, 
/* 73 */        INTEGER BlockSize, 
/* 74 */        INTEGER BufferSize, 
/* 75 */        INTEGER RetentionPeriod, 
/* 76 */        INTEGER RowsPerInstance, 
/* 77 */        INTEGER SecondarySpace, 
/* 78 */        INTEGER UnitCount, 
/* 79 */        INTEGER VigilElapsedTime, 
/* 80 */        INTEGER VigilWaitTime, 
/* 81 */        INTEGER VolumeCount, 
/* 82 */        VARCHAR AccessModuleName, 
/* 83 */        VARCHAR AccessModuleInitStr, 
/* 84 */        VARCHAR DirectoryPath, 
/* 85 */        VARCHAR ExpirationDate, 
/* 86 */        VARCHAR IndicatorMode, 
/* 87 */        VARCHAR PrimarySpace, 
/* 88 */        VARCHAR PrivateLogName, 
/* 89 */        VARCHAR RecordFormat, 
/* 90 */        VARCHAR RecordLength, 
/* 91 */        VARCHAR SpaceUnit, 
/* 92 */        VARCHAR TextDelimiter, 
/* 93 */        VARCHAR VigilNoticeFileName, 
/* 94 */        VARCHAR VigilStartTime, 
/* 95 */        VARCHAR VigilStopTime, 
/* 96 */        VARCHAR VolSerNumber, 
/* 97 */        VARCHAR UnitType
/* 98 */    );
/* 99 */  
/* 100 */   APPLY
/* 101 */       (
/* 102 */           'INSERT INTO DB_FTG_SRS_DATALAB.DICOGLOB_VCOBALT (REGLE_OFS,OFS_FIELD_BC801,ME131,DATA_TYPE,DATA_TYPOLOGY,FU_REF,FU_FIELD,FU_FIELD_EN,CODE_RADAR,REGLE_RADAR,DEFINITION_RADAR,MODIFICATION_REGLE_RADAR,ANACREDIT,ANACREDIT_CRITICAL_FLAG,NPE_FBE,CRE,IFRS9,IFRS9_CRITICAL_FLAG,SHS_2018,SHS_CRITICAL_FLAG,STRESS_TEST,STOP_1_BMRC,MANDATORY_OPTIMA,FRANCE_REPORTING_Data,DEFAULTING_RDI) VALUES (:REGLE_OFS,:OFS_FIELD_BC801,:ME131,:DATA_TYPE,:DATA_TYPOLOGY,:FU_REF,:FU_FIELD,:FU_FIELD_EN,:CODE_RADAR,:REGLE_RADAR,:DEFINITION_RADAR,:MODIFICATION_REGLE_RADAR,:ANACREDIT,:ANACREDIT_CRITICAL_FLAG,:NPE_FBE,:CRE,:IFRS9,:IFRS9_CRITICAL_FLAG,:SHS_2018,:SHS_CRITICAL_FLAG,:STRESS_TEST,:STOP_1_BMRC,:MANDATORY_OPTIMA,:FRANCE_REPORTING_Data,:DEFAULTING_RDI);'
/* 103 */       )
/* 104 */   TO OPERATOR
/* 105 */   (
/* 106 */       W_1_o_CSV_job[1]
/* 107 */  
/* 108 */       ATTRIBUTES
/* 109 */       (
/* 110 */           UserName = 'L2efef', 
/* 111 */           UserPassword = '******', 
/* 112 */           LogTable = 'DB_FTG_SRS_DATALAB.DICOGLOB_VCOBALT_log', 
/* 113 */           TargetTable = 'DB_FTG_SRS_DATALAB.DICOGLOB_VCOBALT', 
/* 114 */           TdpId = 'FTGPRDTD'
/* 115 */       )
/* 116 */   )
/* 117 */   SELECT * FROM OPERATOR
/* 118 */   (
/* 119 */       W_0_o_CSV_job[1]
/* 120 */  
/* 121 */       ATTRIBUTES
/* 122 */       (
/* 123 */           FileName = 'testdico.csv', 
/* 124 */           Format = 'DELIMITED', 
/* 125 */           OpenMode = 'Read', 
/* 126 */           DirectoryPath = 'C:\Users\291506\Desktop', 
/* 127 */           IndicatorMode = 'N', 
/* 128 */           TextDelimiter = ';'
/* 129 */       )
/* 130 */   );
/* 131 */  );
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data from your `C:\Users\291506\Desktop\testdico.csv`?

Comment: Did you check if your input file is actually delimited by `';'` and the number of columns match? You can also try to ignore additional columns using `VARCHAR Accept
ExcessColumns = ’y’`

Comment: Thanks for yours replies but it was my fault i forgot to delete hidden rows in exel. Best regards Folks.